# Powershell script compare 2 .csv files?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to make a powershell script that compares 2 CSV files, and make a new .csv fil with the word that isent in 1 of the csv files?

I got 1 CSV file with 24mil words down in column 1.
And i got a nr2 CSV file with 24mil words. I want to compare those 2 list and see what words are missing, iknow 1 mil are  missing.

So is there a way to make a powershell script that compares :) ?

Best Regards

Comment: Check out [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-5.1) and [this brief guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx). Give it a go and post a question if you run into a specific issue.

Comment: I have played with that before, please check this page: http://www.vladsitblog.com/compare-two-csv-files-via-powershell/ hope it helps

Comment: Hi i have made this: $file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testest2\Test1.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\testest2\Test2.csv" 
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property MPFriendlyName -IncludeEqual export-Csv -Path c:\testmantest2.txt

Comment: So i got comparing to work now. so i was wondering is there a way to script it so i can see how many % its done with the comparing ?